# Why doesn't the word "good" display?

Tags: java, arrays

When I run this code, why doesn't the word "good" display?  The value stored in position 0 of Array1 and Array2 is 1 for both.

```
public class ArrayStuff {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double value = 1;

        Double[] Array1 = new Double[10];
        Array1 = new Double[] {1.0};

        Double[] Array2 = new Double[10];

        Array2[0] = value;

        int i = 0;

        System.out.println(Array1[0]);
        System.out.println(Array2[i]);

        if (Array1[0] == Array2[i])
        {

            System.out.println("good");

        }
     }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

In Java, when one asks

```
Double d1 = ...;
Double d2 = ...;
if (d1 == d2) {
    System.out.println("Equal");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not Equal");
}
```

the JRE does not unbox the `Double` objects, so it checks whether the two `Double`s are the same exact object.  Here, they aren't.  Note the difference between these two blocks of code:

```
Integer i1 = new Integer(1);
Integer i2 = new Integer(1);
if (i1 == i2) {
    System.out.println("Equal");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not Equal");
}
```

and

```
Integer i1 = Integer.valueOf(1);
Integer i2 = Integer.valueOf(1);
if (i1 == i2) {
    System.out.println("Equal");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not Equal");
}
```

The second version reuses the `Integer` object, so the first prints *Not Equal* and the second prints *Equal*.

Comment: The brother here is onto something... :O  +1

Comment: Thanks Eric, I do see the difference between the blocks of code, but I think it's going to take more research on my part to truly understand the issue.

Comment: Look up the Javadoc for Integer.valueOf.  It keeps a cache of the Integer objects it creates.

Answer (score 3):

You're learning that computers cannot represent floating point numbers to exact precision. The solution is to use code that finds a floating point solution that is "close enough" or else one that uses decimal numbers.

Comment: 1 and 1.0 should be represented the same way.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I was reading a bit about that "problem"...pretty strange.  I'll just change everything to int.

Answer (score 1):

Because finite precision numbers have their [limits](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) especially with regard to comparing them for exact equality.

You should approach the problem by checking if the difference between to values is less than a certain threshold:

```
public final double EPSILON = 0.001;

if (Math.abs(Array1[0] - Array2[i]) < EPSILON)
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

does your first variable has to be a double? I mean with an int you solve that problem.

This raises a question: does this line actually create the array with 10 slots and assigns the first value: 1.0 to the 0 slot in the array or fails to create the array correctly?

```
 Double[] Array1 = new Double[10];
    Array1 = new Double[] {1.0};
```

If not then that would be why, that code below is not working for you. Not showing you the "good" word.

```
   if (Array1[0] == Array2[i])
    {

        System.out.println("good");

    }
```

...
However, maybe if you change to 1.0 as value in the first variable... but its not the same to compare doubles.. its not recommended.

```
Double Value = 1.0;
```